# Getting vi/vim syntax highlighting used by certain user

Tags: vim, text-editors, text-editing, vi, syntax-highlighting

At work most web-development we do, is done in vi/vim, on a debian-server.

Sometimes we have to alter some files as root, and the syntax-highlighting-model of that user (root) is absolutely awesome. My problem is that the guy that set the syntax has gone, and I have absolutely no idea where the highlighting is defined.

So, if I wanted to know what kind of syntax is used by a particular user (in vi/vim), where should I look, or what command should I type to get those pretty (and eye-friendly!) colours whenever I use my personal user to edit stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look in the same place you would have configured your vim environment if you were that user, the `.vimrc` file, `.gvimrc` file, and `.vim` directory in that users home directory. For the root account, on a linux host that's likely to be /root/.

Make sure you're authorized to go poking around in there before you do so.

Comment: Both this and the answer below is awesome, wish I could tag both as _the_ answer. Anyway, although this probably is a _bit_ more permanent a solution than getting the colour-scheme, I'm not that fond of editing (or reading, listing, looking at, thinking of and/or writing about) files I´m not _explicitly_ supposed to touch since there´s some pretty business-critical stuff on that server, I will probably try getting the colour-scheme before poking my nose around where I shouldnt!

Comment: @Marcus Hansson if you like it, accept one .

Answer (score 1):

One year and half I had to struggle with a "black box" made by someone who left the company. I felt a little bad about it because it was too obvious that what it did and how it did it was a large bit over my head. After too much hair-pulling I decided to hit the Human Resources for the guy's phone number.

I called him 5 minutes after.

Problem solved.

But Dyslexic Tangent's advice seems the most reasonable to me.

Also you can type `:echo g:colors_name`to get the name of the colorscheme in use. Maybe you can find it on vim.org.

Comment: _:echo g:colors_name_ pretty much what I was looking for! Although, as you said, @Dyslexics answer probably solves the problem in a more, **ahem**, permanent way, this is way the lazy man will walk (IE moi).